# JMeter Threads Getting blocked after sometime in test

Tags: jmeter, blocked-threads

Using JMeter 5.4.1 and JDK 11 in Non-GUI mode, running at 40 Thread at 5 requests/sec.

- All Listeners Off
- Disabled all assertions, relying on application logs
- Groovy used as scripting language in JSR223, using to emulate Pacing between requests
- Heap Size increased to 12 GB

After around 40 mins or sometime 70 mins, JMeter stops generating load as seen on Web Server logs. I ran Visual VM on JMeter machine, hooked into JMeter process and took a Thread Dump.

1. Majority of my threads are in Monitor State
2. Log as below:
   '''

   "Script11 - GetRequest 11-1" #61 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=13390.63ms elapsed=4266.73s tid=0x000001d1599d9800 nid=0xee0 waiting for monitor entry  [0x000000ca924fe000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
   at java.io.PrintStream.println(java.base@11.0.11/PrintStream.java:881)
   - waiting to lock <0x0000000500857638> (a java.io.PrintStream)
   at org.apache.jmeter.reporters.Summariser.formatAndWriteToLog(Summariser.java:329)
   at org.apache.jmeter.reporters.Summariser.sampleOccurred(Summariser.java:208)
   at org.apache.jmeter.threads.ListenerNotifier.notifyListeners(ListenerNotifier.java:58)
   at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.notifyListeners(JMeterThread.java:1024)
   at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:579)
   at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489)
   at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.11/Thread.java:834)

   ```
   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None
   ```
3. "0x0000000500857638" is Locked on

   "Script09 - GetRequest9 9-2" #55 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=13562.50ms elapsed=4266.74s tid=0x000001d1599d5000 nid=0x13e0 runnable  [0x000000ca91efe000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
   at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(java.base@11.0.11/Native Method)
   at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(java.base@11.0.11/FileOutputStream.java:354)
   at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(java.base@11.0.11/BufferedOutputStream.java:81)
   at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(java.base@11.0.11/BufferedOutputStream.java:142)
   - locked <0x0000000500857660> (a java.io.BufferedOutputStream)
   at java.io.PrintStream.write(java.base@11.0.11/PrintStream.java:561)
   - locked <0x0000000500857638> (a java.io.PrintStream)
   at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(java.base@11.0.11/StreamEncoder.java:233)
   at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(java.base@11.0.11/StreamEncoder.java:312)
   at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flushBuffer(java.base@11.0.11/StreamEncoder.java:104)
   - locked <0x00000005008577b8> (a java.io.OutputStreamWriter)
   at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flushBuffer(java.base@11.0.11/OutputStreamWriter.java:181)
   at java.io.PrintStream.write(java.base@11.0.11/PrintStream.java:606)
   - locked <0x0000000500857638> (a java.io.PrintStream)
   at java.io.PrintStream.print(java.base@11.0.11/PrintStream.java:745)
   at java.io.PrintStream.println(java.base@11.0.11/PrintStream.java:882)
   - locked <0x0000000500857638> (a java.io.PrintStream)
   at org.apache.jmeter.reporters.Summariser.formatAndWriteToLog(Summariser.java:329)
   at org.apache.jmeter.reporters.Summariser.sampleOccurred(Summariser.java:208)
   at org.apache.jmeter.threads.ListenerNotifier.notifyListeners(ListenerNotifier.java:58)
   at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.notifyListeners(JMeterThread.java:1024)
   at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:579)
   at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489)
   at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.11/Thread.java:834)

   ```
   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None
   ```

Heap Utilization is around 1.5GB, allocation is 12 GB
CPU Utilization on host machine is around 15%
Any suggestions on how to avoid the JMeter threads getting blocked ?

Thanks.